# How do I print from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm a beginner in a CS class learning python. Not sure if I'm phrasing this question correctly but I have a dictionary of three paint colors red, blue, green, with their associated number (prices) as 35, 25, 23 in that order. I'm trying to have the user input their choice answering the question "Choose a color to paint the wall:" and then outputting the cost of their chosen color.

This is the dictionary I made:

```
paintColors = {
   'red': 35,
   'blue': 25,
   'green': 23
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access elements in a dictionary you always use brackets and the key you want to access, so to get the cost of the red element you would do this:

`paintColors["red"]`

To print that just use a print statement:

`print(paintColors["red"])`

Now if we want to access an arbitrary element, for example input from a user, we need to replace `"red"` with a variable, and set that variable from user input.

To set a variable from user input, we use the input function:

`my_fancy_variable = input()`

And to print something to the user we provide the string we want to print to the input function:

`my_fancy_variable = input("Choose a color to paint the wall:")`

So now we have the color in my_fancy_variable, so we can use it to access the cost in the dictionary:

`print(paintColors[my_fancy_variable])`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I wasn't sure if I worded my question correctly because I'm still learning the terms and names of functions but that's what I was trying to ask. Thanks for your help!
Also I just made this account yesterday so I'm also new to this website and posting questions

Answer (score 3):

With any dictionary, you access the value associated with a key like this:

```
my_dictionary[key]
```

So to print the value of `'green'` you would do

```
print(paintColors['green'])
```

Of course you can replace the explicit key with a request for user input

```
print(paintColors[input('Choose a color to paint the wall: ')])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting data from a dictionary, you either use

```
paintColors['green']
```

or

```
paintColors.get('green')
```

You use the dict[key] value if you know it will be there since it will throw a keyError if the key is not in the dictionary. If you want to be able to allow for None values, then you should use dict.get(key) since it will return `None` if it can't be found in the dictionary.